# PHP PostgreSQL Multiple Queries in Transaction

Tags: php, postgresql

Here's the scenario, table 1 is one-to-many to table 2, and table 2 is one-to-many with table3.  Table 3's records are assigned to table 1 at creation, and assigned to table 2 on an action in a later process (this process).  At the time of the queries both table 1 and table 2's primary keys are known.  If I run an `UPDATE` followed by a `SELECT` in the same transaction will the `SELECT` reflect the `UPDATE`?  And when I fetch results is the `UPDATE` going to mess with that?

SQL:

```
UPDATE table3
SET fk_table2 = ?
WHERE fk_table1 = ? AND fk_table2 IS NULL;

SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4,
    COALESCE(field5, (SELECT default_table3_field5 FROM table1 WHERE table1.pk = table3.fk_table_1)) AS field5
FROM table3
WHERE fk_table1 = ? AND fk_table2 = ?;
```

PHP:

```
$prep = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$prep->execute([
    $table2_pk,
    $table1_pk,
    $table1_pk,
    $table2_pk
]);
$detail = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Yes, the select should reflect the update.  Not sure, though, if after the update, if other transactions might have run which also did DML again `table3`.

Comment: That is not a concern as the next time this script is executed it will go on the next batch.  How about a PHP fetch on the `SELECT` after the query?

Comment: Should be OK...unless you have a setup like something on AWS, where maybe the instance your app hits hasn't been replicated from the node where the original update happened.